# How to subset filenames in bash `ls` output

Tags: bash, unix, grep

So I have a list of files that start with a date (yyyymmdd) and then they have different endings. I would like to filter all dates and the find the uniq ones and count them. So something like this pseudocode:

`ls | grep 'file[0:8]' | unique | wc -l`

But this obviuosly doesn't work. So is there any way on how to do this more or less easily?
The data I have looks something like this:

```
20160124_vv_iw2.slc           20170118_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par  20190120_vv_iw2.slc.par
20160124_vv_iw2.slc.par       20170915_vv_iw2.slc           20190120_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par
20160124_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par  20170915_vv_iw2.slc.par       20200911_vv_iw2.slc
20160827_vv_iw2.slc           20170915_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par  20200911_vv_iw2.slc.par
20160827_vv_iw2.slc.par       20180113_vv_iw2.slc           20200911_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par
20160827_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par  20180113_vv_iw2.slc.par       20200923_vv_iw2.slc
20170118_vv_iw2.slc           20180113_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par  20200923_vv_iw2.slc.par
20170118_vv_iw2.slc.par       20190120_vv_iw2.slc           20200923_vv_iw2.slc.tops_par
```

Comment: Code which doesn't do what you want is a terrible way to tell us what you do want.

Comment: sorry about that. I don't know a lot of bash and actually just wanted to ask if there is anything like the string indexing in e.g. python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```sh
printf "%-8.8s\n" * | uniq | wc -l
```

More generally, you could do something like

```sh
for file in *; do
    echo "${file:0:8}"
done | uniq | wc -l
```

Like any line-oriented approach, this will break if you have file names with newlines in them.

If you just want to split at the first underscore, `"${file%%_*}"` does that.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
ls -1 | sed -E 's/^[^_]+_//' | sort -u | wc -l
```

or

```
ls -1 | sed -E 's/^[[:digit:]]+_//' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: thanks:) This is splitting the data on `_` I guess? But is there any way to really subset the output with numerical indeces in bash?

Comment: @Lenn, given your filename pattern it's the same - see the alternative

Comment: Don't use `ls` in scripts. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I don't think you need to `sort` separately, as the files will already be sorted by `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner, combined with `uniq | wc -l`

```
perl -le 'print sort /^(\d+)/ for glob "*";' | uniq | wc -l
8
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`glob "*"` returns the list of all files and directories.
`/^(\d+)/` returns the regex matches, here, the stretches of digits at the beginning of the file names. Use something like `/^(\d{8})/` if you need the exact number of digits.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Comment: thanks a lot! Always wanted to have a look into perl, but don't know if it's really worth it for my usecases